# Again with filling in a plot

Tags: plotting, code-review, filling

I really don't understand how filling works, and here I am with a new question about.

I need to colour the region in the first quadrant, created by the functions $x+2$ and $-3x+5$. Hence $x$ runs from zero to $5/3$. I tried but I really don't know how to give the right command.

Those are my failures.

```
Plot[{x + 2, -3 x + 5}, {x, 0, 5/3}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

---

```
plot1 = Plot[{x + 2, -3 x + 5}, {x, -2, 4}, 
PlotLegends -> "Expressions"];
plot2 = Plot[{x + 2, -3 x + 5}, {x, -2, 4}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}];
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

And so on...

[image]

What I wish for, is to shade the region for $0<x<5/3$, and generated by the two curves. In few words, the quadrilateral under the two lines, but above the $x$ axis.

Comment: Can you explain precisely what kind of filling you want? Or make a sketch?

Comment: @user293787 Sorry, going to add the plot!

Comment: It might be easier to just combine `Plot` for the lines with `RegionPlot` for the filling. I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want, but is this close: `Show[
 RegionPlot[
  y < x + 2 && y < -3 x + 5 && x < 5/3, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -0, 5}],
 Plot[{x + 2, -3 x + 5}, {x, 0, 4}]
 ]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

You haven't said clearly what you want filled. Perhaps one of these.

```
Plot[{Min[x + 2, -3 x + 5], x + 2, -3 x + 5}, {x, 0, 5/3}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> Axis}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{Max[x + 2, -3 x + 5], x + 2, -3 x + 5}, {x, 0, 5/3}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> Axis}]
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!